# Unable to copy files from host to guest or vice versa using virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am using Oracle VM Virtual Machine, host is windows and guest is Ubuntu. I am unable to copy files from windows to ubuntu or vice versa.

I have looked into the below link

https://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/09/copy-paste-virtualbox-host-guest-machines/

which says i need to make changes in the settings and make both the **shared clipboard** and **drag and drop** option as bidirectional and then try copying the files from windows to ubuntu

I made the changes as suggested still I was unable to copy the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to VMware Workstation -> Edit -> Preferences -> Workspace.
and Check the 'Enable all shared folders by default' check box. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j92wQ.jpg)

Comment: I am using Oracle Vm VirtualBox Manager.. This does not have edit option in it. It has settings and shared folders under it...

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is correct. Try to copy your files to the desktop in your guest OS.

Note: You can drag and drop only certain types of files from windows.

> The following formats are handled by the Oracle VM VirtualBox drag and
> drop service:
>
> Plain text: From applications such as text editors, internet browsers
> and terminal windows.
>
> Files: From file managers such as Windows Explorer, Nautilus, and
> Finder.
>
> Directories: For directories, the same formats apply as for files

[More info in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/guestadd-dnd.html)